# Масштабирование iframe

Tags: javascript, html

Нужно уменшить масштаб страници подгружаемой через айфрейм.

```
<iframe src="http://rutracker.org/forum/index.php" width="100px" height="100px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"/>
```

Нужно чтобы в этом блоке страница выводилась полностью без скролла.

Answer (score 3):

По специфике безопасности к содержимому фрэйма средствами js обратится нельзя, а значит размеры и стили содержимого так просто изменить не получится. Смотрите в сторону граббинга и парсинга.